Function exclusion for a plugin
I have the following code:
function auto_link_post_titles( $content, $post_id, $field ) {
    $excluded_ids = array(); // Put the IDs of the pages you want to exclude here
    $excluded_field_names = array(); // Put the names of the fields you want to exclude here
    
    if(!in_array($post_id, $excluded_ids) && !in_array($field['name'], $excluded_field_names)) {
        // Sets the post type(s) we'll retrieve.
        $desired_post_types = array( 'my_post_type', 'my_other_post_type' );
        // This is to get all published posts from all post types.
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => $desired_post_types,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // this is to retrieve all posts
        );

        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        // Here are looping through each post and replace the title in the content with a link.
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $post_title = esc_html( $post->post_title ); // Here we are getting the post title.
            $post_link  = esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); // Here we are getting the post link.

            // Create a link element
            $link = '<a href="' . $post_link . '" target="_blank">' . $post_title . '</a>';

            // Here we are replacing the plain text title with the link.
            $content = str_replace( $post_title, $link, $content );
        }   
    }

    return $content;
}

// We have apply the function to the content of posts.
// Note the number of parameters is set to 3 here
add_filter( 'acf/load_value', 'auto_link_post_titles', 10, 3 );

Unfortunately, this code breaks it "Ninja Tables" and "Ninja Tables Pro" plugin.
Question, my problem:
Is it possible to exclude this function for specific plugin? And if yes, how? (Plugin loads ACF values.)

With the help of given line you should be able to check if the request is related to Ninja Tables. Also you can modify this if you have another condition to detect the plugin's context.
In this case we have used did_action('ninja_tables_loaded') to checks if the action ninja_tables_loaded has been fired, which might be specific to Ninja Tables.
The given code needs to be added below $excluded_field_names = array(); This code will check the context for Ninja Table and if it's true then it will return from here without further processing.
// Check for Ninja Tables context
if ( isset( $_GET['ntb'] ) || did_action( 'ninja_tables_loaded' ) ) {
    return $content;
}


Works perfect! You are amazing! Thanks. :)

You are very welcome, I am glad I could help you out.
